# Android Listener example to hold current TextView elements on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

I have a main Activity and several Fragments. On each fragment I have several TextView elements. I want to change font size of TextViews on the current displayed Fragment from Main Activity. Therefore I want to hold list of TextView elements on the currentFragment using a Listener. 
But I don't know how to implement such Listener? 
Is the listener right way to do that?

If there is a another way to achieve this, I wanted to know. Any answers welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented as below. It works well fine but I don't know how clear solution it is.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //

}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.smallFontSize:
                FontSizeHelper.updateFontSize(Constants.fontSize1);
            return true;
            case R.id.mediumFontSize:
                FontSizeHelper.updateFontSize(Constants.fontSize2);
                return true;
            case R.id.largeFontSize:
                FontSizeHelper.updateFontSize(Constants.fontSize3);
                return true;
            case R.id.extraLargeFontSize:
                FontSizeHelper.updateFontSize(Constants.fontSize4);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}


public class FontSizeHelper {

   public static List<View> viewElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void initFontElements(){
        viewElements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void addFontEelements(View view){
        viewElements.add(view);
    }

    public static void updateFontSize(int fontSize){
        for(View v : viewElements){
            if(v instanceof TextView){
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(fontSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_fragment, container, false);
//initialize empty list for View objects.
        FontSizeHelper.initFontElements();

//add View object/TextViews into list
FontSizeHelper.addViewEelements(textView1);
FontSizeHelper.addViewEelements(textView2);
FontSizeHelper.addViewEelements(textView3); 
//..etc
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you could just access the current fragment's `TextView` object from the Main Activity and use the `setTextSize()` method.

Comment: Now you say it, I can access current displayed fragment's objects from main activity. But I have for now implemented a FontSizeHelper class to hold textView objects. This way like me much clear. But there  should be a better way I think.

Comment: Post some code so we can understand your situation better.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a list of TextViews and provide a method to add the textviews to the list.

And you also provide a method to signal the activation state. This method will go through the list of textviews calling the changes you need one by one.

From your main activity you will call fragment.changeListeningTextViews();

This goes in the Fragment:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> listeningTextViews;

public void addListeningTextview(TextVew tv){
    //Here check if the text view is already added not to add it twice.

    listeningTextViews.add(tv);
}

public void changeListeningTextViews(){
    for(TextView tv : listeningTextViews){
        tv.setFont(...);
        //What you want called on each TextVeiw
    }
}
```

In onCreateView you add the text views to the list:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aview);
addListeningTestview(textView1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.anotherview);
addListeningTestview(textView2);
...
```

Note: If it were the other way round when you need the Main Activity to listen on events coming from the fragment the solution would be different and the it would involve a custom Listener interface to be implemented by the Main Activity.

Comment: I did actually something like your answer. Thanks